# NivoSlider and Lightbox javascripts conflicting

Tags: lightbox, dreamweaver, nivo-slider

On my portfolio website (www.jyschan.com), I'm trying to showcase my design projects using the Lightbox script, since it looks very professional and also saves me the hassle/headache of recreating a redundant html page for each project preview.

On my portfolio.html file in Dreamweaver, I have both the NivoSlider and Lightbox javascripts included in the header. Everytime I tweak the code, only one of the scripts seems to work. Currently, only the slider works, even though I coded all the thumbnails to preview with Lightbox.

My main question for now is--do the NivoSlider and Lightbox javascripts conflict with each other? Or do I just have an error in my coding?

Any help would be appreciated...thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify which Lightbox implementation (link to library) you are using? Maybe you can even check what js library it's using under the hood. If both components are using jquery (in the same version) there shouldn't be any conflict. Otherwise it depends on implementation.